Intuitive Graphing for Oblique Lines in the Complex Plane
For a complex number $z$, when we have two moduli equal to each other, the graph of the set of all $z$ satisfying the equation produces a line.
For example, $|z|=|z+2|$, the set of all $z$ that satisfy this is a vertical line with $\mathrm{Re}(z)=-1$.
$$|z|=|z+2|$$
$$|z|^2=|z+2|^2$$
$$zz^*=(z+2)(z^*+2)$$
$$zz^*=zz^*+2z+2z^*+4$$
$$z+z^*=-2.$$
Now say $z=a+bi$,
$$a+bi+a-bi=-2$$
$$a=-1.$$
So $z=-1+bi$, which is a vertical line with real part $-1$.
If we reobserve the aforementioned moduli, $|z|=|z-(-2)|$, and plot the points $(0,0)$ and $(-2, 0)$. We can connect these two points with a line. The set of $z$ that satisfies the moduli equation happens to be a line orthogonal to the midpoint of both of these points.
Now, what if it is not as trivial, $|z-(a+bi)|=|z|$, can we apply a similar process and draw an oblique line orthogonal to their midpoint?

Yes, you can draw the oblique line orthogonal to their midpoint.
Easiest to dispense with Complex Analysis, and instead, apply Geometry to $~\Bbb{R^2}.~$
In the first example, the locus of all points equidistant to $~(-2,0)~$ and $~(0,0)~$ is the perpendicular bisector of $~\overline{(-2,0),(0,0)}.$
The exact same approach works for the second problem.  The desired locus is the perpendicular bisector of $~\overline{(a,b),(0,0)}.$
